# unable to delete a sms from android sms inbox

Tags: android

I have developed an application to process SMS from inbox and process it.  After processing delete that SMS from inbox.  But an error occurs while deleting SMS.

I tried this code:

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
String phoneNo, msg;
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    phoneNo = cur.getString(2);
    msg = cur.getString(11);

    // do some process

    String pid = cur.getString(1);
    String uri = "content://sms/conversations/" + pid;
    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
}
```

Comment: make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>` permission in manifast

Comment: @imrankhan yes that was the problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you get the SMS write permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```